# Why is $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}x^kdx = k!$?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, indefinite-integrals, factorial

I was answering some math exercises, and by accident, I 'discovered' the following equation:

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}x^kdx = k!
$$

for instance, if $k=3$, we have the following (using an online integral calculator, i.e. Wolfram):

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}x^3dx = 3! = 6
$$

However, I could not figure out how the equation makes sense... Is there a way to analytically transform the integral to $k!$ ?

Comment: You can prove it by induction.

Comment: It just requires repeated integration by parts.

Comment: You would need to prove that the integral obeys the same recurrence as the factorial: $k!=k \cdot (k-1)! $$$ $$ Just as Euler did. And the same initial condition, for example $1!=1$

Comment: @YuriyS, okay, I am not as smart as Euler though for sure, could you elaborate? thanks

Comment: @LinkL, just as Kavi Rama Murthy said,  integration by parts

Comment: For further informations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$I_0=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-at} dt =\frac{1}{a}~~~(1)$$
D.w.r.t. $a$ both sides you get
$$I_1=\int_{0}^{\infty}t e^{-at} dt =\frac{1}{a^2}$$
Again differentiate to get
$$I_2=\int_{0}^{\infty} t^2 e^{-at} dt =\frac{2}{a^3}$$
Finally , differentiate w.r.t. $a$ $k$-times to get
$$I_k=\int_{0}^{k} t^k e^{-at} dt = \frac{k!}{a^{k+1}}$$
Put= $a=1$ to get $I_k=k!$

Answer (score 3):

For a proof by mathematical induction:

**Basic step**: 
 $$\int_{0}^{\infty }{{{e}^{-x}}}{{x}^{0}}dx=0!\ and\ \int_{0}^{\infty }{{{e}^{-x}}}{{x}^{1}}dx=1!\ $$

**Induction step** :
$$\int_{0}^{\infty }{{{e}^{-x}}}{{x}^{k+1}}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty }{\overbrace{{{x}^{k+1}}}^{u}\overbrace{{{e}^{-x}}dx}^{dv}}=\left. {{x}^{k+1}}{{e}^{-x}} \right|_{\infty }^{0}+\left( k+1 \right)\int_{0}^{\infty }{{{e}^{-x}}{{x}^{k}}dx}=\left( k+1 \right)k!=\left( k+1 \right)!$$

note that $\left. {{x}^{k+1}}{{e}^{-x}} \right|_{\infty }^{0}=0$  by repeated application of L'Hôpital's rule.